# CalendarView doesn't reset after getDate()

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the numerical value of a date out of a CalendarView, which should be possible by using `calendarView.date`. I have attached this function to a button that displays the `long calendarView.date` in a TextView. It works fine the first time I press the button but doesn't update the TextView when I select a new date and press the button again.

Here's my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.androidas.mindscape

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.tlbMain))
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu:Menu):Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolmenu, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {

    R.id.actAdd -> {
        textView2.text = "reset" //my idea was to reset the text first, but this didn't work.
        textView2.text = (clvMain.date).toString()
        true
    }

    R.id.actPersonalities -> {
        // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
        // as a favorite...
        true
    }

    R.id.actList -> {

        true
    }

    else -> {
        // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
        // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

}
```

Where `R.id.actAdd` is an item in the overflow menu of the action bar.

The way I see it, the TextView should update with the newly selected date as soon as I press the button. Any ideas? Maybe it's simple, but I can't figure it out.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this declaration `var dateString: String = Date().toString()` before onCreate().

Add this code in onCreate():

```
clvMain.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
    dateString = "$year/$month/$dayOfMonth"
}
```

and use dateString instead of (clvMain.date).toString()

Comment: Wow, thank you. Any idea as to why it doesn't reset when calling directly?